# How to retrieve autoId to delete value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to allow users to delete comments upon pressing the delete button. When comments are submitted, they're created using autoId and the header of the node will be the postId to see what post they commented on.

```
  "comments" : {
    "-LmfZZis5ovtBwfm_4xR" : {
      "-LoHu5Qv3BmuHTsSlthj" : {
        "creationDate" : 1.567980283717026E9,
        "text" : "Kkkk",
        "uid" : "64r3dgTN6xMhHYhptFlsFWX0dLk2"
      },
      "-LoHuPohuQ3eUtDWL_G-" : {
        "creationDate" : 1.567980367209054E9,
        "text" : " Ok",
        "uid" : "64r3dgTN6xMhHYhptFlsFWX0dLk2"
      }
    }
  },
```

I do not know how to retrieve the autoId so current logged in users can delete their comments. Here is the code for submission

```swift
  func didSubmit(for comment: String) {

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        print("post id:", self.post?.postId ?? "")

        print("Inserting comment:", comment)


        let postId = self.post?.postId ?? ""
        let values = ["text": comment, "creationDate": Date().timeIntervalSince1970, "uid": uid] as [String : Any]

        Database.database().reference().child("comments").child(postId).childByAutoId().updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in

            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to insert comment:", err)
                return
            }

            self.uploadCommentNotificationToServer()

            if comment.contains("@") {
                self.uploadMentionNotification(forPostId: postId, withText: comment, isForComment: true)
            }

            self.containerView.clearCommentTextView()
        }

        }
```

Comment struct

```swift
struct Comment {
    var commentId: String!
    let user: User
    var creationDate: Date!
    let text: String
    let uid: String!

    init(commentId: String!,user: User, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.commentId = commentId
        self.user = user
        self.text = dictionary["text"] as? String ?? ""
        self.uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""

        if let creationDate = dictionary["creationDate"] as? Double {
            self.creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: creationDate)
        }

    }

    var post: Post?


    func deleteComment() {
        guard let postId = self.post?.postId else { return }

     let commentsRef = Database.database().reference().child("comments")
        commentsRef.child(postId).child(commentId).removeValue()




    }




}
```

Code to fetch the comments

```swift
    var comments = [Comment]()

    func fetchComments() {
        guard let postId = self.post?.postId else { return }
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("comments").child(postId)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
             let commentId = snapshot.key
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            guard let uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String else { return }

            Database.fetchUserWithUID(with: uid, completion: { (user) in
                let comment = Comment(commentId: commentId, user: user, dictionary: dictionary)

                self.comments.append(comment)
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })

        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to observe comments")
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: ;You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do

Comment: Thanks Frank, will edit question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to delete a node, you must know the full path to that node.

There are two ways to know the key of the product you want to delete:

1. You've passed it along your app from the moment when you loaded the data.
2. You have some other value that allows you to perform a query on the database to look up the key.

The first option is the most common, as you'll typically be loading the data from the database already to display it to the user. In that case you should "simply" pass the [key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#key) of the data along when displaying the [value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#value).

Once you have the key of the product/child node, you can delete it with:

```
let postId  = "-LmfZZis5ovtBwfm_4xR"
let commentId  = "-LoHu5Qv3BmuHTsSlthj"
let commentsRef = Database.database().reference().child("comments")
commentsRef.child(postId).child(commentId).removeValue()
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for responding so quick. How exactly can I grab the key when I have multiple comments with different Ids coming in? If you explained it already in your answer I apologize, just a little confused mate. Is it not possible to have the autoId equal the second Id and the postId equal the first?

Comment: Or would I have to make  ```let firstId = postId ``` and ```let secondId =```  the autoId somehow

Comment: I wasn't sure what the two auto ID levels in your post mean, which is why I named them `firstId` and `secondId`. I now see that they are `postId` and `commentId`, so updated my answer. Either way you will to know both keys to be able to delete a specific comment. Approach 1 in my answer means that you will need to pass both those keys along from when you load the data from the database, which unfortunately you didn't show in your question.

Comment: I see.. I will edit my question to include the code I use to fetch the data in my question Thanks Frank! I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Where you now fetch `snapshot.value`, you also need to fetch `snapshot.key` and store that with the comment. Then when the user clicks a comment, you know its key, combine it with self.post?.postId`, and thus can use the code in my answer.

Comment: Hey Frank, it appears I ran into an issue I am not familiar with, normally when I accept an answer I am good to go. I am keeping your answer accepted because the comment was deleting upon tapped. However, the comment is no longer being deleted. I can still print out the commentId fine and it shows, but when trying to delete nothing happens. I updated my code, do you see anything wrong? I have no idea what happened

Comment: Code that worked doesn't usually stop working without other changes (either in code or in the context that the code runs in). Did you for example change the security rules for your database? Or anything else about how you pass the data along to `deleteComment`?

Comment: I’m not sure, I’ll debug and see what I can find. CommentID is now producing nil, I can still print the postId though so that’s good. I’ll dig deeper and look into it. Thanks!